# How do I run my newly created hello_world.py file from a command prompt window?

Tags: python

I have my first ever `hello_world.py` file saved in `documents\python_work`. It runs fine in the Sublime text editor but when I try to navigate to it through a command prompt window, it can't seem to find it. I open a command prompt and type `cd documents` and it works. I type `dir` and it shows me the files, but when I type `cd python_work` (which is the folder my file is in) I get:

> The system cannot find the path specified.

The textbook had me add `C:\Python` and `C:\Python\Scripts` to the `PATH` environment variables (not too sure why, just following directions), so perhaps I made a mistake during this process?

Comment: Make sure you can navigate to the Python file in file explorer.

Comment: I can. I see it in the folder I saved it in, but when I click on it to open the file it looks like a window is about to open but then closes too fast for me to see which program it was trying to start up. Not sure if that means anything, but it's definitely there.

Comment: Probably what is happening is that your code is being launched in a command prompt, and then as soon as your code stops executing (after printing "hello world"), it immediately exits and closes the command prompt.

Comment: What is the output of `dir` in `Documents`?

Comment: You should use an IDE like IDLE or Spyder to run it and have time to read. Otherwise you can launch a cmd / prompt windows .. look for you script and run it..

Comment: Don't click on it in Explorer. That will run the python interpreter python.exe on it and after it finishes the command window will immediately close. So you will not see the output from your program, or, to be realistic if this is your first program, the error message telling you why the program won't run. Instead, type `cmd` in the search bar bottom left to open a Windows console, then navigate to the folder where the program is using the  `cd` command (paste the folder name from Explorer after `cd`, as in `cd C:\users\me\Documents\mypythonfolder`), then type the name of the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are the the same folder as the file, type `python`(or `py`, depending on your python version) `python file.py` to run it.

A quick way to get to the folder is find it in the file explorer, and where it shows the file path, click there and type 'cmd' and hit enter. It will open up the Command Prompt from that folder so you don't have to manually navigate to it.

Comment: Eureka! That worked! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Np! glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

You can go to the File Explorer, right-click on your `hello_world.py` file and then:

```
Properties > Details > File Path
```

and then proceed to copy that path in your `cmd`.